# Comparing alternative structural equation models x -> m -> y VS m->x->y

Tags: anova, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

I'm new to SEM and I'm not sure if my way of testing mediations sounds right...

```
model1 <- ' 
    X1 =~ q12+q13+q14+q15+q16
    M1 =~ q23+q24+q25R+q27+q28+q29
    Y1 =~q32+q33
    Y2 =~q52+q53+q54+q55+q56+q57
    Y3 =~q58R+q59+q60+q61R

# regressions
        # a path
         M1~ a1*X1
         
         # b path
         Y1 ~ b1 * M1
         Y2 ~ b2 * M1
         Y3 ~ b3 * M1
         
         # c prime path 
         Y1 ~ cp11 * X1
         Y2 ~ cp12 * X1
         Y3 ~ cp13 * X1

    # indirect and total effects
         a1b1 := a1 * b1
         a1b2 := a1 * b2
         a1b3 := a1 * b3
         total1 := cp11 + a1b1
         total2 := cp12 + a1b2
         total3 := cp13 + a1b3

'
```

As an alternative model, I want to test M -> X -> Y

```
model1 <- ' 
    X1 =~ q12+q13+q14+q15+q16
    M1 =~ q23+q24+q25R+q27+q28+q29
    Y1 =~q32+q33
    Y2 =~q52+q53+q54+q55+q56+q57
    Y3 =~q58R+q59+q60+q61R

# regressions
        # a path
         X1~ a1*M1
         
         # b path
         Y1 ~ b1 * X1
         Y2 ~ b2 * X1
         Y3 ~ b3 * X1
         
         # c prime path 
         Y1 ~ cp11 * M1
         Y2 ~ cp12 * M1
         Y3 ~ cp13 * M1

    # indirect and total effects
         a1b1 := a1 * b1
         a1b2 := a1 * b2
         a1b3 := a1 * b3
         total1 := cp11 + a1b1
         total2 := cp12 + a1b2
         total3 := cp13 + a1b3

'
fsem1 <- sem(model2, missing="fiml", estimator = "MLR", data = data)
```

This is a simpler version of my models, and when I actually compare my two models, I see something like below:

[image]

I'm wondering a) if I can conclude that the models do differ and the one with smaller AIC/BIC/Chisq is a better one, and b) also, I ran my models with MLR and I'm not sure if anova is okay to use for model comparison here?

Really appreciate any help with this!!

Comment: what is lavaan?

Comment: It's a package in R for structural equation modeling. I've edited the question, because it's not about lavaan, it's about SEM.

Answer (score 2):

In short: Yes.

Your models are not nested, so you should not be doing a chi-square test (using the anova() function) to compare them. (You can tell, partly because you have zero df for the difference).

The AIC/BIC can be used to assess the difference in fit between the models, but because the df are the same, the difference in the AICs is the same as the difference in the chi-squares.

Comment: Oh I see and thanks a lot! What do you suggest then I should do to compare them..?? or you mean I should rely on the AIC/BIC?

Comment: Yes, you should use AIC/BIC.